# Add a new column to Pandas Dataframe based on values from other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

This is my first time posting here. I tried almost everything but could not find a solution to it. Please help!

I have a python pandas dataframe which has these columns - ID, Step, X, Y. Each ID has a number of steps. I want to add a new column (new_id) to it which takes integer values starting from "1". And provides the same value for each ID if it contains same values for "X" & "Y" for all the steps using a for loop. Otherwise, add 1 to the previous new_ID value

```
DataFrame (df)
ID        Step      X       Y
1001        0      100     200
1001        1      200     300
1001        2      100     250
1001        3      150     200
1002        0      150     200
1002        1      200     250
1002        2      250     300
1002        3      300     150
1003        0      100     200
1003        1      200     300
1003        2      100     250
1003        3      150     200
1004        0      150     200
1004        1      200     250
1004        2      250     300
1004        3      300     150
1005        0      125     220
1005        1      200     250
1005        2      250     300
1005        3      300     150
```

```
Newly Created DataFrame (df)
ID        Step      X       Y     new_id
1001        0      100     200       1
1001        1      200     300       1
1001        2      100     250       1
1001        3      150     200       1
1002        0      150     200       2
1002        1      200     250       2
1002        2      250     300       2
1002        3      300     150       2
1003        0      100     200       1
1003        1      200     300       1
1003        2      100     250       1
1003        3      150     200       1
1004        0      150     200       2
1004        1      200     250       2
1004        2      250     300       2
1004        3      300     150       2
1005        0      125     220       3
1005        1      200     250       3
1005        2      250     300       3
1005        3      300     150       3
```

Comment: It's not clear what your algoithm is.  Please explain more clearly "And provides the same value for each ID if it contains same values for "X" & "Y" for all the steps using a for loop. Otherwise, add 1 to the previous new_ID value"

Comment: If you have an algorithm to generate your new column as a list (called, for example, `new_values`) you can them simply write `df['new_id'] = new_values` ... that will automatically create a new column called 'new_id'.